# Image will not draw on screen using multiple files

Tags: lua, drawing, love2d

The image that is supposed to display is not displaying. I am putting the player code and main.lua in separate files. It is my first time using multiple files in any programing language

I have tried to create a rectangle to make sure it's existing. The rectangle does show up, but the image does not.

```
this is player.lua
    pl = {   -- pl stands for player.
    x = 100, -- player's x coordinate
    y = 100, -- player's y coordinate
    spd = 4, -- player's speed
    dir = "", -- player's direction (n=north s=south e=east w=west
    img = {
        n = love.graphics.newImage("images/player/playern.png"),
        s = love.graphics.newImage("images/player/players.png"),
        e = love.graphics.newImage("images/player/playere.png"),
        w = love.graphics.newImage("images/player/playerw.png"),
        }
    }


function pl.update() --Movement and stuff
    if love.keyboard.isDown("w") then
        pl.y = pl.y - pl.spd
        pl.dir = "n"
    elseif love.keyboard.isDown("a") then
        pl.x = pl.x - pl.spd
        pl.dir = "w"
    elseif love.keyboard.isDown("s") then
        pl.y = pl.y + pl.spd
        pl.dir = "s"
    elseif love.keyboard.isDown("d") then
        pl.x = pl.x + pl.spd
        pl.dir = "e"
    end
end

 function pl.draw() --draws the player. determines graphic to load and draws it.
 if dir == "n" then
    love.graphics.draw(pl.img.n)
 elseif dir == "s" then
    love.graphics.draw(pl.img.s)
 elseif dir == "e" then
    love.graphics.draw(pl.img.e)
 elseif dir == "w" then
    love.graphics.draw(pl.img.e)
 end
    end
```

```
    function love.load()
    require("player")
    love.graphics.setDefaultFilter("nearest")
    end

    function love.update(dt)
        pl.update()
    end


    function love.draw()
        pl.draw()
        love.graphics.print(pl.dir,0,0)
        love.graphics.rectangle("fill", pl.x, pl.y, 32, 32)
    end

I expect the images (playern, players, etc.) to appear but they do not show up. No error messages appear when running. I don't know if its the player or main.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that in `pl.draw()` you are using `dir`, instead of `pl.dir`. Additionally if you want the player image to move with the player you need to add the `x` and `y` variables as parameters. See the example below:

```
if pl.dir == "n" then
    love.graphics.draw(pl.img.n, pl.x, pl.y)
```

Comment: I am just plain dumb and blind. Thank you!